# Can not create a new HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I referred to [this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/) to learn how `HashMap` works. In my code when I write `Map h1 = new HashMap();` eclipse underscores `HashMap()` with red squiggle. I do not know why, and it is the same as written in the tutorial.

Comment: What does "red squiggle" has to say about this? P.S. Why don't you add type parameters, just for good practice?

Comment: are you using Eclipse or Android studio? In Eclipse, press Ctrl+Shift+O; and in Android Studio I think you need to press Ctrl+Shift+I or Alt-Enter I'm actually not sure which because I used eclipse for android.

Comment: Wow this tutorial doesn't even have type parameters. That sort of neglect is irritating, because he even said it's `Map<K,V>` above! Silly tutorial. Anyways, do this: `Map<String, Integer> h1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Comment: @Zhuinden no not Andrid studio, it is eclipse Luna. it seems i have to import those libraries manually the short-cut does not work

Comment: @MariusType red squiggle says: `mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap to Map`

Comment: @Zhuinden I tried your suggestion, unfortuantely, `HashMap` is still underscored with the red squiggle and eclipse says: `The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Integer>`

Comment: hmm your Eclipse is probably set to a wrong compiler version. You need to set it to project level 1.6 I'll look it up in a sec what to do with it.

Comment: Okay, select the project, go to File -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Configure Workspace Settings -> Compiler Compliance Level -> 1.6.

Comment: Also, make sure you have a new version of the JDK installed, if I know correctly then even using the JDK8 allows you to create JDK6 applications, so the latest is best.

Comment: @Zhuinden i tried it, and still the same error

Comment: if the project specific settings are enabled, make sure that the project is at compiler level 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must import the correct classes.

Add this in between your `package` and `class` declarations:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

Or in Eclipse, press `Ctrl-Shift-O` to wizard-import.

**Note**

The tutorial you're using seems to be pretty old and uses raw types. 
This is strongly advised against since Java 5 and [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

You can try checking the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) to learn more about `Map`s.

Comment: I tried importing these libs manually, but eclipse does not acceot `import java.util.HashMap;` dont know why?

Comment: Have you put the `import` statements in the right place? After the `package` declaration and before the `class` declaration, that is.

Comment: What do you mean "Eclipse doesn't accept" it? Have you removed the JRE from your build path?

Comment: when i import the libs the one at the first line in your answer, eclipse underscores the whole line with red

Comment: Try to check you have a recent JRE in your build path and that your compiler compliance is > Java 1.2.

Comment: should it be 1.2 or 1.6?

Comment: 1.2 for `Map` and `HashMap`. 1.5 for generics, but you're not using them yet.